# How to describe a raw file body in RAML 1.0?

Tags: api, documentation, raml

I have an API endpoint which allows user to upload a file and a request payload is a raw file contents. How can I describe this in a RAML documentation?

I use suck structure, but it doesn't seem correct to me

```
post:
  description: Use this endpoint to upload a new image.
  headers:
    X-File-Name: Image file name.
  body:
    file:
    description: Send raw file contents in a request payload
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In RAML 1 you can use the file type:

```
types:
  customFile:
    type: file
    fileTypes: ['*/*'] # any file type allowed
    maxLength: 1048576
```

And then use it like this:

```
/someresource:
  post:
    body:
      application/octet-stream:
        type: customFile
```